# How to get the week number from date in PHP with US and ISO standards?

Tags: php, api

When I try to get week number from the date, I am getting different numbers with ISO and US standard.

```
$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 01, 01, 2006);
$week = (int)date('W', $date);
echo "Weeknummer: ".$week;
```

Because ISO standard says that week start on Monday...US standard says that week start on Sunday

How can I sort this out using PHP code or some external API available for this? Any paid one something ?

This link will tell you how to check this online
http://www.onlineunitconversion.com/day_week_number.html

Please Help... I want to get the US standard week number

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious way to do what you want utilising the PHP date functions themselves (that I know of), the next best alternative would be to use a function to calculate your week number seperately.

```
function week_number($stamp){
    return date('W', $stamp+(60*60*24));
}
```

http://codepad.org/IvX9jqEj

Comment: Sadly enough this still seems to best way in 2018. Having an internationalisation that begins on a sunday results in the following code using "pure php" solutions:
`php > echo (new DateTime('2018W500'))->format('w W-o d-m-Y');  
//returns 0 49-2018 09-12-2018`

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_default_timezone_set` and define default timezone. Then you should have right number.. [From php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: That will not work as this function only sets the **timezone** for `date()`. As seen in the manual, "**ISO-8601** week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP 4.1.0)"

Comment: That function is used to get the current date of any country (Location basis).. Not like it get the location from date :)

Comment: Sorry didnt understand question well... try this 
$week = date('W', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2006)+3600*24); :)